# How do I enrich a package object?

Tags: scala, enrich-my-library

I recently discovered that one can use the <strike>Pimp</strike> Enrich My Library pattern to add methods to companion objects using `.type`:

```
object Whatever { }

implicit class WhateverExtensions(val obj: Whatever.type) {
    def greet = println("Hi!")
}

Whatever.greet
```

Unfortunately the same doesn't seem to work for package objects like `scala.math`:

```
implicit class MathExtensions(val obj: scala.math.type) {
    def min(x: Money, y: Money): Money = ???
}
```

I get the following compiler error:

```
Error:(153, 47) type mismatch;
 found   : math.type
 required: AnyRef
Note that math extends Any, not AnyRef.
Such types can participate in value classes, but instances
cannot appear in singleton types or in reference comparisons.
    implicit class MathExtensions(val obj: scala.math.type) extends AnyVal {
                                                 ^
```

Is it possible to enrich a package object?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think it's possible in that fashion, though the documentation is extremely thin. The compiler is clearly treating it differently than a singleton. Even if that method compiled, `import scala.math._` would *certainly not* import your `min` method, as there is nothing to trigger the implicit conversion. And well, if `math.customMin` was possible, that would require two imports.

It *is* possible in another way. We can define anything we want in the `scala.math` package. We can't define methods at the top-level, though, so we need to employ some object trickery to make it work.

```
package scala.math

object intMin extends ((Int, Int) => Int) {
    def apply(x: Int, y: Int): Int = x + y
}
```

Some test:

```
import scala.math._

object Test extends App {

    println(intMin(4, 10))

}
```

Comment: Not much in the docs at all: http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/09-top-level-definitions.html#package-objects. It seems impossible to get the type of that thing: `type T = '`math'`.type` gives "Error:(5, 12) stable identifier required, but scala.<math: error> found.
  type T = `math`.type".

Comment: See also: http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/packageobjects/packageobjects.html